# Arduino Web Client getting no response

Tags: xml, http, get, arduino

I am trying to get XML data to use for a weather service, I am using Open Weather Map which has a handy xml and API system. However I seem to get no response when using my code. I have used the WebClient demo code, and that seems to work and print the response to the Serial console. However when using my code I do not get a response.

When I use the code below, I get the serial response "Connected to XML data." but when the program gets to the loop, I do not get the "reading HTML data", I instead get "Disconnecting". Can someone please advise how I can change the code? (The serial console output is below the main code.)

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

int cityID = 2644487;
char APIkey[33] = "SOME API KEY"; //32 length

byte mac[] = {0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 89);
byte gateway[] = {192, 168, 1, 254};
byte subnet[] = {255, 255, 255, 0};
//byte dns[] = {81, 139, 57, 100};

//Open weather map xml
char server[] = "http://api.openweathermap.org";
int port = 80; //usually 80 for http.



EthernetClient client;
int temperature = 0;
char buff[80];
byte pos = 0;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void setup()
{
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);//used to disable the SD Card
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Initialising...");

  // Start Ethernet
  //Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dns, gateway, subnet);
  if (!Ethernet.begin(mac)) { //if DHCP does not automatically connect
    Serial.println("Using gateway and subnet");
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dns, gateway, subnet);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Using mac and ip");
  }
  delay(1000); // delay to give the ethernet shield a second to connect.

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connecting to OWM server using cityID: ");
  Serial.println(cityID);
  Serial.print("Using API key: ");
  Serial.println(APIkey);

  if (client.connect(server, port))
  {
    Serial.println("Connected to XML data.");
    client.print("GET /data/2.5/weather?id=2644487&appid=SOME API KEY&mode=xml&units=metric HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    client.print("HOST: http://api.openweathermap.org\r\n");
    client.print("Connection: Close\r\n");
    client.print("\r\n");

  }


  else
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect.");
  }


}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void loop()
{
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    Serial.println("Reading HTML data");
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}
```

Serial Console Output

```
Initialising...
Using mac and ip

Connecting to OWM server using cityID: 23047
Using API key: SOME API KEY
Connected to XML data.

Disconnecting.
```

Comment: `http://api.openweathermap.org` is not a valid hostname.

Comment: what would I have to use instead? That's the address for accessing it when using a PC. Sorry, I don't know much about how GET commands work

Comment: Someone already told you that in your previous question.